# Use symbol to replace function

Tags: function-construction, replacement, syntax

I'm trying some transformations and they are getting complicated.
It's common in physics to replace functions by symbols so you term get shorter.

Lets say I have transformation

```
xr[A_,B_] := K A + L B + KK A^2 + LL B^2,
```

where `A = A[x_]` and `B = B[x_]`

I want to input some random values of `x`.
But for the code to be readable I want to substitute the quadratic part as

```
H =  KK A^2 + LL B^2
```

How do I go about this?
I don't want to define H as a function, since that would make me have to write

```
xr[A,B] = xr[A,B,H] = xr[A,B,H[A,B]] = xr[A[x],B[x],H[A[x],B[x]]]
```

which just gets unwieldy.

Essentially I just want to be able to write H such that mathematica would understand that
when I define

```
xr[A,B] := K A + L B + H
```

Output of sending a `x` value to it would be

```
xr[A[x],B[x]] = K A[x] + L B[x] + KK A[x]^2 + LL B[x]^2.
```

Hopefully you can understand what I'm trying to do.
Thank you for your help.

Edit: This is just an example of function. Of course It wouldn't be useful in this case and I also know there are reasons why this specific type substitution wouldn't be a healthy practice but what are the alternatives.

Comment: Why can't you just define: `H[A_, B_] = KK A^2 + LL B^2;
xr[A_, B_] := K A + L B + H[A, B]` ?

Comment: Try this: `xr[A_, B_] := k A + l*B + kk A^2 + ll B^2;  xr[A, B] /. kk A^2 + ll B^2 -> H` which returns `H + A k + B l` .

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can **display** the unevaluated functions in any desired format.

```
Format[A[x_]] := A;
Format[B[x_]] := B;

xr[a_, b_] := K a + L b + KK a^2 + LL b^2
```

Then,

```
xr[A[x], B[x]]

(* K A + KK A^2 + L B + LL B^2 *)
```